# Is there a stamp event for polymer templates?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am trying to focus an input element inside of a polymer template every time it stamps its contents.  The problem is that I cannot select the input element until the template has loaded.  Currently, I am just using setTimeout to focus the input 100ms after the template should load, but I want to know if there is a more elegant solution.  Also, the autofocus attribute doesn't work, because the template may un-stamp and re-stamp many times.  Right now, my code looks something like this (this is inside a polymer element definition):

```js
Polymer({

  // ...

  showInput: false,

  makeInputVisible: function() {
    this.showInput = true;
    var container = this.$.container;
    setTimeout(function() {
      container.querySelector("#input").focus();
    }, 100);
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <template if="{{showInput}}">
    <input id="input" is="core-input" committedValue="{{inputValue}}" />
  </template>
</div>
```

But I would prefer something more like this:

```js
Polymer({

  // ...

  showInput: false,

  makeInputVisible: function() {
    this.showInput = true;
  },

  focusInput: function() {
    this.$.container.querySelector("#input").focus();
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <template if="{{showInput}}"
            on-stamp="{{focusInput}}">
    <input id="input" is="core-input" committedValue="{{inputValue}}" />
  </template>
</div>
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to focus the input after it's values are updated? I don't quite understand what you mean with "stamp".

Comment: The polymer template renders its contents inert by default.  That means they do not exist in the DOM, and no scripts are executed.  That, in turn, means that they cannot be selected until the template has bound, or "stamped" them into the DOM.  See [the polymer docs on template](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/template.html).  I want to focus the input the instant the template is bound, but I cannot select the input until just after the template has finished placing it in the DOM.  That is why I have been using the setTimeout, but I would prefer some kind of 'on-bind' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Polymer 1.0, there is a 'dom-change' event fired by templates when they stamp.  However, there is a significant performance cost to using dom-if templates since they need to manipulate the dom tree.  It would be much better to do something like this:

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="input" hidden="[[!showInput]]" value="{{inputValue::input}}">
</div>
```

```js
observers: [
  '_showInputChanged(showInput)',
],

_showInputChanged: function (showInput) {
  if (showInput) {
    this.$.input.focus();
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest would to observe the value, e.g.:

```
// you already have an Id assigned to the input, so you can use that reference.
.. 
 showInputChanged: function() {
  this.$.input.focus();
 }
..
```

You can also define your own event handlers if you need cross component communication:

```
..
 ready: function() {
  this.addEventListener("on-stamp", function(e) {
   if(e.detail.value != undefined) this.$.input.value = e.detail.value; 
   this.$.input.focus();  
  });
 }
..
```

Then you can use fire an event from anywhere and even set the value, e.g.

```
   setValue: function(s) {
    this.fire("on-stamp", {value: s});
   },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot select the input with [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding), because it is inside a template.  Also, I have tried observing the value, but the showInputChanged function gets called before the template is bound so I cannot select the input.

Comment: As a side note, you can select dynamically generated content with auto node finding using this.$$.input in your case. You'd just have to make the ID unique, and then know which one you wanna select from the outside.