# Add keyEventTarget on singel element with IronA11yKeysBehavior Polymer

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I got a dom-module that contains one `<authoring-unit>` per object in my model.
The elements will look different based on attributes that is given to the objects in the model. I control this by `<template is="dom-if>`

They all contains an `<p>` element that is contenteditable. the `<p>` elements contains text that the unit object contains. I'm trying to save the edited data when you press enter with the help of `IronA11yKeysBehavior`.

The problem is that I can't bind it to the specific `authoringunit` the only thing that seems to work is to bind it to the whole body with document.body but then it reacts on enter on the whole site and saves all of the units to the model:

```
 //Case when unit is active:
<dom-module>
<template item="{{unit}}" as="unit">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{unit.attributes.active}}">
    <paper-material id="authoringunit" elevation="3" class="editing-mode">

        <p class$="{{unit.attributes.type}}" id="unit-content"
        contenteditable="true">{{unit.attributes.content}}
        </p>

    </paper-material>
   </template>
// Case when unit is in-active

<template item="{{unit}}" as="unit">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{!unit.attributes.active}}">
    <paper-material id="authoringunit" elevation="0">

        <p class$="{{unit.attributes.type}}" id="unit-content"
        contenteditable="false">{{unit.attributes.content}}
        </p>

    </paper-material>
   </template

</template>
</dom-module>

<script>

Polymer({
 is: 'edit-authoring-unit',

 behaviors: [
  Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior
 ],

 properties: {
  unit: Object,
  keyEventTarget: {
   type: Object,
   value: function() {
     //this is what sucks, here i would like to return the singel
     //authoringunit to bind them to the keypress.
     //I thought this would work this.$.authoringunit; but it return undefined

     return document.body;
   }
 }
},

 keyBindings: {
  '* enter': '_saveInput'
 },

 _saveInput: function() {
   //SAVE TO MODEL
  };

 ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because at the time the value function is called `this.$.authoringunit` is not defined yet. You can however set the `keyEventTarget` in the `ready` callback.

```
    ready: function(){
        this.keyEventTarget = this.$.authoringunit;
    },
```

If your target element is wrapped in a dom-if, use the `attached` handler instead.

```
    attached: function(){
        this.keyEventTarget = this.$.authoringunit;
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, it still gives me undefined :(

Comment: I've also tried with this:
     this.keyEventTarget =     Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#authoringunit');

Comment: You are right. I had a simple example working, but it did not  have the dom-if templates. So it won't work for you.

Comment: It will work with the dom-if, if you put the code into the attached handler. However, it won't be dynamic. That is, if unit.attributes.active changes at runtime, you would need to reset keyEventTarget

Comment: hmm, that sucks. So you don't think there's a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: It's an interesting problem. First I thought that you could just make keyEventTarget  a computed property that depends on unit.attributes.active. However, when unit.attributes.active changes, the template has not been stamped yet and your node can't be found. And there appears to be no event for template stamping ([related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953336/is-there-a-stamp-event-for-polymer-templates)).

Comment: Also note that your approach will result in duplicate ids, as stamped elements will just be hidden but remain in the dom tree by default ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if)).

Comment: is it a better way to decide what happens with classes and JS instead of "dom-if" ?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you ultimately want to achieve. There are usually several ways to do the same thing. For example your two dom-if blocks look almost identical. Maybe you could only use one and update the attributes when the state changes. Or you stick with the dom-if, use different ids in each block and listen for changes to the state and then update the keyEventTarget (inside an async).

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Maria , I now change the attributes instead :) made life much easier.